# Is oracle driver can be installed on eclipse-link? or in glass fish? or where and how?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I'm currently creating a batch using JPA, with hierarchy of Tasklet-> accessor-> service-> processor, and i'm using Glassfish for my database. But then when I run`

> [ERROR] [com.acts.core.jpa.dao.base.DAOFactory] - Exception
>   encountered with message Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse
>   Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception
>   Description: Configuration error.  Class
>   [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] not found..  This means that the
>   default constructor for the class
>   com.aeon.pms.orm.dao.impl.ConstantDaoImpl cannot be invoked. Throwing
>   DAOExecution Exception...`

is encountered. Is it mainly configuration error like the logs said? Do I need oracle driver? and i want to learn how to install it?
I'm using eclipse-link and I'm not familiar with this as i'm more used to using Netbeans, that's why I'm not sure if i'm missing on configurations. I'm so in need of help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` you need to add one jar file to your project library,for this go to your oracle installation dir and find for **classes12.jar** and add it to your project library(whatever is netbeans or eclipse).

Or if you are not using any IDE then copy that jar file and past to program dir(where your .class is stored) and then run following command in cmd or terminal for run program.

```
java -classpath classes12.jar;. yourprogramclassname
```